# HTTPRequest for XML - only appear if there is a certain sub-child

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Right, Below is a simple javascript request to display the content that is in the XML Document.

I have lot's of different versions of XML's that are all from the same place but some are structured slightly different, so some elements inside the **KISCOURSE** tag do not have a **TITLE** - when this happens it throws out my coding structure and makes it appear wrong.

Is there a way, if **TITLE** is not found inside a **KISCOURSE**, then do not display that **KISCOURSE** and just move onto the next one.

Just incase, For an example on how the XML Data looks, see: http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/XML/london_metropolitan_university.xml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/XML/london_metropolitan_university.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INSTITUTION");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("KISCOURSE");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)

  { 
  document.write("<div class='CourseArea'><h3 id='CourseTitle'>");

  // TITLE
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</h3>");
  document.write("<p class='ForP'>-&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("MODE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);     
  document.write("</p><div class='clear'></div>");

  // UCAS CODE
  document.write("<p id='ucascode'>");
  document.write("<b>UCAS CODE</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("UCASCOURSEID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</p>"); 

  // READ MORE LIGHTBOX
  document.write("<img src='<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/info-icon.png' width='15' style='margin:0px 2px 0px -4px;' />");
  document.write("<a class='various' href='#ReadMore'>Read More</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

  // VISIT COURSE LINK
  document.write("<a class='courselink' href='");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CRSEURL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("' target='_blank'>Visit course website</a>");
  document.write("</div>");

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue  (skip to the next loop iteration) if the title is missing:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("KISCOURSE");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
  if(x.getElementsByTagName("TITLE").length == 0) continue; //this skips to the next.

  document.write("<div class='CourseArea'><h3 id='CourseTitle'>");
```